# FancyBox is closing on form focus and re-opening with just the form contents

Tags: jquery, fancybox, forms

I've got a form with a `textarea`, a couple of `input`s, and a `submit`. The fancybox opens perfectly, but when I click any one of the fields for focus, the box immediately closes and re-opens with just the form contents. With the new box only containing the form, if I try to get focus, the same thing happens again, re-opening just the form again.

HTML Form:

```
<form>
<fieldset class="profile">
<legend>Email John Doe:</legend>

<!-- PASS NAME (to query email) to the script -->
<input type="hidden" name="who" value="John Doe" />

<label for="from">Your Email:</label><br />
<input type="email" id="from" name="from" /><br />
<label for="message">Message:</label><br />
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.profile').fancybox({
        closeClick  : false
    });
});
```

I've worked with fancybox before, but this has me completely stumped. I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing, but I've got no clue what that stupid thing is.

PS: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the content is being loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the culprit is `<fieldset class="profile">` which is bound to fancybox so trying to get `focus`(clicking on) also affects the `fieldset` tag, which triggers fancybox over and over again.

Use a different class to trigger fancybox or change the class of the `fieldset` tag.

Comment: Shoot! You're right. I don't even know why I put that there. All good now.